# git_remote_connect always return wrong

Tags: c, git, libgit2

i'm new in libgit2. and my problem is about `git_remote_connect` function, this problem has been confusing me for many days.

when i use `git_remote_connect`, it always return wrong, the message is:`This transport isn't implemented. Sorry`

The code is simply looks like:

```
git_remote *remote = NULL;
git_remote_load(remote, git_repo, remote_name);

// output the correctly result, just like run: git remote -v
g_message("remote user:", git_remote_name(remote)); // github-username
g_message("remote url:", git_remote_url(remote)); // git@github.com/github-username/Repo

if (git_remote_connect(remote, GIT_DIRECTION_FETCH) < 0) {
    const git_error *e = giterr_last();
    g_error("connect wrong!\n"
            "message: %s",
            e->message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol you're asking libgit2 to use was not included while compiling. Install the development package/headers for whatever package is needed and compile libgit2 again. The cmake output will tell you what was discovered; see the README for the libraries.

As an aside, `git@github.com/github-username/Repo` is a local path, which is always available, so it's unlikely that this is the URL which libgit2 is trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

you should enable SSH in `CMakeLists.txt`

```
OPTION(USE_SSH              "Link with libssh2 to enable SSH support"        ON)
```